# Are there any differences between Protestant and Catholic theology concerning the distinction between demonic possession from mental illness?

Tags: catholicism, protestantism, demon-possession, mental-illness, discernment

Is there a difference between Catholic and Protestant Theology in regards to what constitutes Demonic possession as opposed to mental illness?

Answer (score 4):

From [this article](http://www.gotquestions.org/psychological-demon.html) by [Got Questions Ministries](http://www.gotquestions.org/about.html), who describe themselves as *"Christian, **Protestant**, conservative, evangelical, fundamental, and non-denominational"*, the answer to *"How do we distinguish a psychological disorder from demon possession?*" is

> The short answer to this question is that the Bible does not speak to
>   distinguishing between demon possession and a psychological disorder.
>   Because God chose not to equip Christians for this task, we should
>   probably assume this is not something we are called to do.

In the Gospels, for example in [Matthew 9](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?version=RSVCE&search=Matthew%209), there is a clear distinction between *'every disease and every infirmity'* that Jesus healed and the casting out of demons.

In the **Catholic Church**, *"before an exorcism is performed, it is important to ascertain that one is dealing with the presence of the Evil One, and not an illness."*

cf. [Catechism of the Catholic Church 1673](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p2s2c4a1.htm#1673)

> **1673** When the Church asks publicly and authoritatively in the name of Jesus Christ that a person or object be protected against the power
>   of the Evil One and withdrawn from his dominion, it is called
>   exorcism. Jesus performed exorcisms and from him the Church has
>   received the power and office of exorcizing.<sup>1</sup> In a simple
>   form, exorcism is performed at the celebration of Baptism. The solemn
>   exorcism, called "a major exorcism," can be performed only by a priest
>   and with the permission of the bishop. The priest must proceed with
>   prudence, strictly observing the rules established by the Church.
>   Exorcism is directed at the expulsion of demons or to the liberation
>   from demonic possession through the spiritual authority which Jesus
>   entrusted to his Church. Illness, especially psychological illness, is
>   a very different matter; treating this is the concern of medical
>   science. Therefore, before an exorcism is performed, it is important
>   to ascertain that one is dealing with the presence of the Evil One,
>   and not an illness.<sup>2</sup>
>
> <sup>1. Cf. *Mk* 1:25-26; 3:15; 6:7, 13; 16:17.</sup>
>   <sup>2. Cf. CIC, can. 1172.</sup>